# Google News API - Utilização do Curl com PHP

Tags: php, api, google

Estou tentando utilizar a `API` do `Google News`, não consigo listar as notícias que eu quero de determinada categoria, gostaria de fazer com `PHP` para que consiga listar e armazena-las no banco de dados.

Peguei um exemplo na ***Internet***:

```
$details_url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=video-games&apiKey=minhachave";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo $geoloc = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

Não está listando nada, alguém tem experiência com essa `api`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu rodeio o teste e do jeito que está o seu código ele dá uma mensagem de erro assim:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

então para contornar isso que é a verificação do `SSL` configure o seu código para não fazer essa verificação:

```
$details_url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=video-games&apiKey=minhachave';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // aqui a alteração
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // aqui a alteração
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

a partir dessas duas configurações o resultado é retornado. [Um leitura recomendada sobre: PHP CURL emite erro “unable to get local issuer certificate”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110991/php-curl-emite-erro-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) aqui no próprio site.

***Observação:*** *Eu recomendo isso só num ambiente de teste, na produção geralmente os servidores tem o certificado e pode ser utilizado sem essas configurações e vale lembrar que segurança é um tema debatido e deve existir para ajudar manter um sistema saudável.*

***Resumo:*** o seu código exige a verificação `SSL` onde o seu servidor não está configurado corretamente e com isso o resultado não é trazido, mostrando o erro informado nessa resposta e foi feito um código exemplo que como poder utilizar no seu ambiente de teste, mas, não recomendado no ambiente de produção, pelo motivo **segurança**.

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar!